# Android TCP/IP and GUI to other thread communication - Tic Tac Toe Multiplayer

Tags: java, android, multithreading, tcp, handler

So here's the deal. I'd like to implement the multiplayer Tic Tac Toe using Android. I deployed multithread server using Java, but I'm struggling with Client. As far as I know You should use background thread to handle the communication, and leave the UI thread just to UI stuff. I have some problems with developing the game loop and thread communication. I decided to use Handlers instead of AsyncTask.

I think that the loop should be implemented in background thread and look kinda like this:
Get the info from UI using Handler
Write the data to output stream to the server
Read the data from the input stream from the server
Process the data
Send the data to UI using other Handler.

I am testing this using Eclipse and emulators acting as a client. The problem is I just can't setup the handlers. One handler UIHandler is send as a parameter to the ClientThread Constructut, Net Handler is obtain through a method from Client thread into the UIThread.

I read that I need to use the Looper to process incoming data. Can't I just call the handleMessage method in an endless loop? I srsly don't know how to deploy this. I would be greatful for any ideas.

Main activity Client Class:

```
    package com.example.tictactoecliet;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        ClientVocabulary {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Socket client;
    private PrintWriter pw;
    private EditText etIp;
    private TextView tvStatus;
    private Button bCon;
    private Socket socket;
    PrintWriter out;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private RadioButton rbVsPlayer, rbVsAI;
    private ViewFlipper vF;
    private ClientThread cT;
    private ImageButton[][] board = new ImageButton[5][5];
    private Handler h, clientHandler;
    SocketAddress sockaddr;


    /******************************************************************************************/

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();
        setupUIHandler();
        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }



    /*****************************************
     * initialize
     * 
     * @return nothing ffs
     ******************************************/

    private void init() {

        etIp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etIP);

        tvStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
        rbVsAI = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbAI);
        rbVsPlayer = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb2players);
        bCon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCon);

        //
        // // listeners
        //
        vF = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.vF);
        bCon.setOnClickListener(this);
        board[0][0] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iB_1A);
        board[0][1] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iB_2A);
        board[0][2] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iB_3A);
        board[0][3] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iB_4A);
        board[0][4] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iB_5A);

        board[1][0] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iB_1B);
        board[1][1] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iB_2B);
        board[1][2] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iB_3B);
        board[1][3] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iB_4B);
        board[1][4] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iB_5B);

        board[2][0] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iB_1C);
        board[2][1] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iB_2C);
        board[2][2] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iB_3C);
        board[2][3] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iB_4C);
        board[2][4] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iB_5C);

        board[3][0] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iB_1D);
        board[3][1] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iB_2D);
        board[3][2] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iB_3D);
        board[3][3] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iB_4D);
        board[3][4] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iB_5D);

        board[4][0] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iB_1E);
        board[4][1] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iB_2E);
        board[4][2] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iB_3E);
        board[4][3] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iB_4E);
        board[4][4] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iB_5E);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

                board[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);
            }// end of inner for
        }// end of outer for

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case (R.id.bCon):
        vF.showNext();
        blockAllTile();
        cT = new ClientThread((short) (rbVsPlayer.isChecked() ? 2:1), clientHandler, etIp.getText().toString());
        cT.start();
            break;
        case (R.id.iB_1A):
            sendLocation(0);
            break;
        case (R.id.iB_2A):
            sendLocation(1);
            break;
        case (R.id.iB_3A):
            sendLocation(2);
            break;
        case (R.id.iB_4A):
            sendLocation(3);
            break;
        case (R.id.iB_5A):
            sendLocation(4);
            break;
        case (R.id.iB_1B):
            sendLocation(5);
            break;
        case (R.id.iB_2B):
            sendLocation(6);
            break;
        case (R.id.iB_3B):
            sendLocation(7);
            break;
        case (R.id.iB_4B):
            sendLocation(8);
            break;
        case (R.id.iB_5B):
            sendLocation(9);
            break;
        case (R.id.iB_1C):
            sendLocation(10);
            break;
        case (R.id.iB_2C):
            sendLocation(11);
            break;
        case (R.id.iB_3C):
            sendLocation(12);
            break;
        case (R.id.iB_4C):
            sendLocation(13);
            break;
        case (R.id.iB_5C):
            sendLocation(14);
            break;
        case (R.id.iB_1D):
            sendLocation(15);
            break;
        case (R.id.iB_2D):
            sendLocation(16);
            break;
        case (R.id.iB_3D):
            sendLocation(17);
            break;
        case (R.id.iB_4D):
            sendLocation(18);
            break;
        case (R.id.iB_5D):
            sendLocation(19);
            break;
        case (R.id.iB_1E):
            sendLocation(20);
            break;
        case (R.id.iB_2E):
            sendLocation(21);
            break;
        case (R.id.iB_3E):
            sendLocation(22);
            break;
        case (R.id.iB_4E):
            sendLocation(23);
            break;
        case (R.id.iB_5E):
            sendLocation(24);
            break;

        }

    }

public void unblockAllTile(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

            board[i][j].setEnabled(true);
        }// end of inner for
    }// 
}   

public void sendLocation(int location){

}

    public void blockAllTile(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

                board[i][j].setEnabled(false);
            }// end of inner for
        }// end of outer for

    }
    private void setupUIHandler(){

        h = new Handler(){

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                Bundle b = msg.getData();
                String content = b.getString("msg");
                if(content.equals(KKIP_ALL_CONNECTED)){
                    tvStatus.setText(KKIP_ALL_CONNECTED);
                }else{
                    Log.i("i no noł", "i no noł");
                }


            }
        };

    }
}
```

Background Thread:

```
package com.example.tictactoecliet;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

public class ClientThread extends Thread implements ClientVocabulary {

    private Socket socket;
    private short game_mode;

    private Handler uiHandler;
    private Handler netHandler;
    private Bundle inMsgBundle, outMsgBundle;
    private final static String TAG = ClientThread.class.getSimpleName();
    private BufferedReader in;
    private String ip, serverResponse;
    PrintWriter out;

    public ClientThread(Short game_mode, Handler h, String ip) {
        this.game_mode = game_mode;
        this.uiHandler = h;
        this.ip = ip;
        inMsgBundle = new Bundle();
        outMsgBundle = new Bundle();

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("Thread started",TAG);
        connectionSetup();
        Log.i("Setup connection",TAG);
        Looper.prepare();
        setupHandler();
        Log.i("Handler set",TAG);
        try {

            play();




        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Looper.loop();
    }// end of run

    public  Handler getHandlerToMsgQueue() {
        while (netHandler == null) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return netHandler;
    }

    // //////////////////////////////////////////
    public void connectionSetup() {
        try {
            Log.i("Setup start",TAG);
            InetAddress serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
            SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(serverAddress, 4321);
            // socket = new Socket("192.168.0.102",4321);
            socket = new Socket();
            socket.connect(sockaddr);
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    socket.getOutputStream())), true);
            out.println(game_mode);

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));
            Log.i("Setup finish",TAG);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
////////////////
    public void setupHandler(){

        Log.i("Handler ready",TAG);
        netHandler = new Handler(){



            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                notifyAll();

            }
        };

        Log.i("Handler done",TAG);
    }
///////////////////////////play//////////////////////////
    public void play() throws Exception{
        String response;
        Log.v("Play start", "Play start");



        try {
            response =null;
            if(in.readLine()!=null){
            response=in.readLine();
            Log.v(response, response);
            }else{
                Log.v(TAG, "Resposne is empty");
            }

            if( response.startsWith(KKIP_WELCOME)){
                Log.i("wow welcome so much", "so much welcome");
                char mark = response.charAt(8);
            }else if (response.startsWith(KKIP_WAITING_FOR_OPPONENT)){


                while (true){


                //updatuj status zegarem, może wait i notify?
             if(response.startsWith(KKIP_ALL_CONNECTED)){



                    Log.v("now we play","play");
                    sendMessageToUI(KKIP_ALL_CONNECTED);
                    response=in.readLine();
                    if(response.startsWith(KKIP_VALID_MOVE)){

                        //update board
                    }else if (response.startsWith(KKIP_MOVED)){
                        int loc = Integer.parseInt(response.substring(15));
                        //update board
                    }else if (response.startsWith(KKIP_VICTORY)){

                    }else if(response.startsWith(KKIP_DEFEAT)){

                    }else if (response.startsWith(KKIP_TIE)){

                    }
                }   

            }//end of while (true)


            //end of if connected 


            }
            out.print(KKIP_QUIT);
            }




         catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            socket.close();
        }       

    }
    private void sendMessageToUI(String msg){
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putString("msg", msg);
        Message m = new Message();
        m.setData(data);
        uiHandler.sendMessage(m);
    }
}
```

The code isn't finished yet, so some methods might seem strange. I am interested in solving the UIThread to BackGroundThread to Server Communication. Nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

`Handler` objects are implicitly tied to the `Looper` running within the `Thread` in which they are created.  Your background thread needs to create its own `Looper` (or use `HandlerThread` to take care of the `Looper` for you.)  Then your background thread needs to communicate its `Handler` back to the main UI thread.